# Virtual machine access to the host ethernet port

Tags: vmware

I am using a Xubuntos virtual machine (Xubuntu with Tinyos) on VMware Fusion and I need the virtual machine to access directly to ethernet port of my Mac.

I want to emulate a direct ethernet cable between the VM and the board I am trying to program (the VM would be 192.168.0.1 and the board 192.168.0.2).

How do I tell VMware to let the VM control directly the Ethernet port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your VM's Network Adapter to use "bridged" networking.

This isn't *exactly* what you are asking for, as the VM will have a different MAC (that's Media Access Control, not Macintosh) address from your host (your Macintosh).  But, from a device elsewhere on the network it will look like both your VM and your Macintosh are directly attached to the same physical network.  The VM will have full control over its network, the same as if it were running on a physical device.

It is not possible in VMware Fusion to "pass-through" a network device to a VM so that it controls the physical device.  But, its unlikely that you actually need that.